# How to get data from Google form responses to another sheet but to one column only?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is the link to
[my Actual Work Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lzFTYmmkBtLOxc6kfTuFi-d9e2sHoQMPiUacbFEXJwc/edit?resourcekey#gid=657028589)..

Google Form:
[Google Form link](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeEYEBMf0463qlaqXgcJjfp5FNKFC-tLzyHV291y_806sOx6A/viewform?usp=sf_link)

Form Responses sheet: This sheet populates google form responses from Google Form.

db_Responses sheet: This sheet is for aligning all data entries from Form Responses sheet into 1 column and the same for its quantity.

*In db_Responses sheet: I used Filter formula to get data per column. example in column A Column header is `TimeStamp`. I used arrayformula with filter.

```
=arrayformula({"TimeStamp";FILTER('Form Responses 3'!A2:A,'Form Responses 3'!B2:B<>"")})
```

When submitting another response from Google Form, does not affect the formula. I used these formula for Columns A, B and C.

As for Column D to Column S, how do I Filter them?

Desired Output:
[image]

Is there anyway I can do this with a formula? or App Script?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Just to make sure that I understood what you would like to achieve correctly, based on the Google Forms answers you are getting a spreadsheet which is the file Id: 1P_xO2g5By8E3Rvej4HPa_HFnKLNVObWe0AgrM6Sk_Yo, but you are looking to use a formula to get the desired output as the file Id: 1ZLdc1S7wzz4LH1x-X34XNHIIyHzVDnoU_AIECTgBUzQ, do you need that desired output in a different spreadsheet file or in the same spreadsheet file as an extra "Sheet"?

Comment: @SamuelLopez, I need both in the same spreadsheet. From Google Form Responses sheet to the desired output sheet.

Comment: `I need both in the same spreadsheet.` Sorry, I find this unclear and confusing - you provided two spreadsheets but it appears that you only want the results to appear in one spreadsheet. May I try to clarify, please correct me if I am wrong. You have a Google Form linked to a Google Sheet file named "Google Form Responses", form submissions appear on sheet/tab named "Form Response". You want to "consolidate" form responses, and you want these to appear in "Google Form Responses" on a sheet named "RESULT". You don't want any form data to be displayed in another spreadsheet file.

Comment: Sorry for that, I edited my post, I linked my actual work sheet and the Google Form.